# ORA-12704: character set mismatch

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, coalesce

Hell when I do:

```
select COALESCE (CORP_ID, 0) from crmuser.accounts;
```

The CORP_ID records which are Null returns 0 but when I do:

```
select COALESCE (EMAIL, 'NO EMAIL') from crmuser.accounts
```

I get an error:

```
ORA-12704: character set mismatch
```

The EMAIL field in NVARCHAR2(30). Is is My Datatype and if so What should I do to return default Values?

Comment: works fine for me ...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you should do

```
select COALESCE (EMAIL, n'NO EMAIL') from crmuser.accounts
```

to convert the literal to NVARCHAR.

eg
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73929/1
vs
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73929/2

Answer (score 2):

This generic fix works with columns defined as either VARCHAR2 or NVARCHAR2:

```
select COALESCE (EMAIL, N'' || 'NO EMAIL') from crmuser.accounts
```

Just add N'' || before your non-Unicode string constant.