# ORA-12704: character set mismatch with nvarchar2 datatype in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I get the error code `ORA-12704` with the following query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(BankDetails.description,'') as description FROM BankDetails
```

The datatype of description column nvarchar2. I'm assuming the  `''` is the cause of the issue as this is not matching with the datatype.

Comment: I would start by renaming `desc` since it is also a keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT COALESCE(BankDetails.description,n'') as description FROM BankDetails
```

Reference

[ORA-12704: character set mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967201/ora-12704-character-set-mismatch)

Comment: I find the "N" prefix quite odd for sql synatx, i prefer the oracle function "to_nchar" - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2116.htm#OLADM694

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `n` variant, to cast the `''` to a `nvarchar`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(BankDetails.description,n'') as description FROM BankDetails
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use this one:

```
SELECT COALESCE(BankDetails.description, NULL) as description FROM BankDetails
```