# character set mismatch coalesce

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem with this query, it tells me the error

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NCHAR got NUMBER
00932.00000 - "inconsistent datatypes: expected% s got% s"
* Cause:
* Action:
Error in line: 54, column: 43
```

the subquery returns the letter "f" or "m" of the sex of the students in which there is more, this works but the problem is how I assign that letter to the variable **Where genero_a =**

```
SELECT NOMBRE, COALESCE(DIRECCION,CORREO, 10) comm
FROM ESTUDIANTE
WHERE GENERO_A =  
    (SELECT GENERO_A
    FROM ESTUDIANTE
    GROUP BY GENERO_A
    HAVING COUNT(GENERO_A) = 
        (SELECT MAX(COUNT(*)) as CONTAR
        FROM ESTUDIANTE
        GROUP BY GENERO_A))
ORDER BY NOMBRE;
```

I am not at all proficient in sql, I appreciate your understanding.

--TABLA ESTUDIANTE

```
CREATE TABLE ESTUDIANTE(
    ID_LECTOR VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE VARCHAR2(50),
    APELLIDO VARCHAR2(50),
    GENERO_A CHAR(1) CONSTRAINT CH_GENERO_A CHECK(GENERO_A IN ('f', 'm')),
    DIRECCION NVARCHAR2(100),
    CORREO NVARCHAR2(50)
);
ALTER TABLE ESTUDIANTE ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ESTUDIANTE PRIMARY KEY(ID_LECTOR);
```

Comment: That means your genero_a is defined as `NCHAR` in your database and you are comparing it with `NUMBER` that is returned from your subqueries. Change your result to `char`.

Comment: the subquery is returning a char "f or "m" , what should I change to char? :S i dont understand, sorry...
edit: Genero_a is defined as CHAR(1)

Comment: Can you post your table structure with datatypes and which one is line 54?

Comment: I has edited the post already with ESTUDIANTE table :)

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is on `COALESCE(DIRECCION,CORREO, 10)`, since all the fields does not have same data types.

**Solution:**
You have to cast `NUMBER` 10 to the similar datatype as of DIRECTION and CORREO.
Simply change the above code to `COALESCE(DIRECCION,CORREO, CAST(10 as NVARCHAR2(2)))`.

> The CAST function converts a value from one data type to another.

Updated query:

```
SELECT NOMBRE, COALESCE(DIRECCION,CORREO, CAST(10 as NVARCHAR2(2))) comm
FROM ESTUDIANTE
WHERE GENERO_A =  
    (SELECT GENERO_A
    FROM ESTUDIANTE
    GROUP BY GENERO_A
    HAVING COUNT(GENERO_A) = 
        (SELECT MAX(COUNT(*)) as CONTAR
        FROM ESTUDIANTE
        GROUP BY GENERO_A))
ORDER BY NOMBRE;
```

Or, From the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967201/ora-12704-character-set-mismatch) you provided,

```
SELECT NOMBRE, COALESCE(DIRECCION,CORREO, N'10') comm
FROM ESTUDIANTE
WHERE GENERO_A =   
   (SELECT GENERO_A
    FROM ESTUDIANTE
    GROUP BY GENERO_A
    HAVING COUNT(GENERO_A) = 
        (SELECT MAX(COUNT(*)) as CONTAR
        FROM ESTUDIANTE
        GROUP BY GENERO_A))
ORDER BY NOMBRE;
```

Or,

```
SELECT NOMBRE, COALESCE(DIRECCION,CORREO, N''||10) comm
FROM ESTUDIANTE
WHERE GENERO_A =   
   (SELECT GENERO_A
    FROM ESTUDIANTE
    GROUP BY GENERO_A
    HAVING COUNT(GENERO_A) = 
        (SELECT MAX(COUNT(*)) as CONTAR
        FROM ESTUDIANTE
        GROUP BY GENERO_A))
ORDER BY NOMBRE;
```

Comment: thanks bro it is working now , i read other post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967201/ora-12704-character-set-mismatch)
but that doesn't work :s why is that ?
I tried add n''  like the example "select COALESCE (EMAIL, n'NO EMAIL')"  the code turns all blue

Comment: @RicardoBarros Answer updated. If it is working you can upvote/accept the answer.

Comment: I accepted already :) thanks @ofisora but i have a doubt, Why does my code in the sql sheet turn blue from the line where I add n'10 'or N' '|| 10 to the end?

Comment: Maybe that's the problem of your sql sheet. I am using notepad++ and checked online editor also, it is working fine.

Comment: mmm yes maybe it's sql developer problem, thanks for all :)